# What is the maximum number of API calls per second that Workday can support

Tags: workday-api, bottleneck

During our implementation, our implementation partner said that Workday can only handle 10 calls per second and drops any beyond that.  Has anyone had the issue and is there a way around it.  We have a number of systems that want to use API integrations but we have avoided it due to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the documentation, you can find the limits for RaaS/REST/SOAP here: [Reference: Integrations and Web Service Limits](https://doc.workday.com/r/3DMnG%7E27o049IYFWETFtTQ/sGhnezv85Vfp9LabNN%7EEWw)